# What am I doing wrong with my assembly x86-64 code?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I have written one of my very first assembly programs today - but I keep getting an error message.

I am using win64 OS and nasm assembler.

This is my code:

```
section .data

section .bss

rcxOfFirst resq 1d
rdxOfFirst resq 1d


section .text
    global _main
_main:


mov ah,2ch  ; display system time
int 21h

mov rcxOfFirst,RCX
mov rdxOfFirst,RDX
```

> time2.asm:18: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands ; My error message
>
> time2.asm:19: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

Comment: Possibly, you need square brackets around your operand to dereference the pointer: `mov [rcxOfFirst],RCX`

Comment: Also note `int 21h` is a 16 bit DOS function while you seem to be writing 64 bit code for a different OS (that you forgot to specify, along with the assembler used). That won't work. Furthermore your program has no ending, it will crash even if you get it to assemble and link.

Comment: How do you invoke nasm?

Comment: An immediate can't be a destination, only memory or a register.  `mov rcxOfFirst,RCX` is basically the same as `mov 12345, RCX`, but with the linker filling in the symbol address at link time.

Answer (score 1):

In the intel syntax, the destination register/address comes first in the operand list and the source comes second.

```
    mov rcx, rcxofFirst ; loads rcx with rcxofFirst.
```

You have mixed up the order of your operands.
Also you seem to be writing 16-bit assembly with 'int 21h' which used in DOS.